# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 Bit - Firefox asks if it could be the default browser every time I open it

Tags: firefox

Nearly every time I open Firefox it asks to be the default browser. As far as I can see Firefox is the only browser installed.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 Bit
HP Envy DV7
Intel® Core™ i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8

Comment: You may have corrupted the profile (for Firefox). This is a known issue, but seldom occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the alert box once then it wont ask again.

Got to Tools --> Preferences --> Advanced --> System Defaults

And make sure that the "Always check to see if Firefox is the default browser on start-up", is Unchecked.  And if you want Firefox to be the default, just click on "Make Firefox the default browser"

[image]

Hope this will help you to avoid alert.